# On Spark's rdd.map(_.swap)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to both Scala and Spark. Could anyone explain what's the meaning of

```
rdd.map(_.swap)
```

? If I look in Scala/Spark API I cannot find `swap` as a method in RDD class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`swap` is a method on Scala [Tuples](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2). It swaps the first and second elements of a Tuple2 (or pair) with each other. For example:

```
scala> val pair = ("a","b")
pair: (String, String) = (a,b)

scala> val swapped = pair.swap
swapped: (String, String) = (b,a)
```

RDD's `map` function applies a given function to each element of the RDD. In this case, the function to be applied to each element is simply

```
_.swap
```

The underscore in this case is shorthand in Scala when writing anonymous functions, and it pertains to the parameter passed in to your function without naming it. So the above snippet can be rewritten into something like:

```
rdd.map{ pair => pair.swap }
```

So the code snippet you posted swaps the first and second elements of the tuple/pair in each row of the RDD.

Comment: for tuples which have been createdusing spark :

Answer (score 3):

This would only be available if `rdd` is of type `RDD[Tuple2[T1,T2]]`, so `swap` is [on the `Tuple2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2)

Answer (score 2):

In Python it works like as follows:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

This will swap **(a, b)** to **(b, a)** in the key, value pair.

Answer (score 1):

For tuples which have been created using spark, use this lambda:

> ```
> RDD map1 : ("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)...
> ```

```
val map 2 = map1.map(a=> (a._2, a._1))
```

This will return the RDD

> ```
> RDD map2 : (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")...
> ```